# Post status check from child pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

We have a "parent" pipeline that compiles some source code and generates artifacts needed for another "child" pipeline.

The "parent" repo master branch has a build validation configured to run “parent”-pipeline when a pull request has been created. Just as an simple gate, if the code wont compile, you will not be able to merge to master.

Now I want to add the "child"-pipeline result to act as another gate similar to the one above.

First, I was thinking that I can do the same as we did for the "parent"-pipeline as a build validation step. But since it depends on the artefacts created from the "parent"-pipeline it would be tricky hence both pipelines will probably be triggered at the same time.

Am I supposed to post an status from the "child" pipeline to the pull request status checks variables? How can I do this or do you have another solution?

Comment: Not get your latest information, is the workaround helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Comment: Is it possible to set the child pipeline to a manual trigger and set the child to trigger when parent is completed. Will the build police be correctly updated in the PR?

Comment: You can set [build completion triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic) to automatic  run child pipeline after parent is completed.

Comment: The build status that can be displayed in the pull request is determined by the "Build Validation" set. If you only set the child pipeline in the "Build Validation", then only the child's status will be displayed in the pr.  Because the "build completion triggers" is set, when the status of the child in the pull request is successful, it means that the parent is also successful.

Comment: Understood, yes, this is an alternative but would be better with fully automatic

Comment: So far, there should be no better way. If this answer is helpful, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround , we can set [build completion triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic) to automatic run child pipeline after parent pipeline is completed.

The build status that can be displayed in the pull request is determined by the "Build Validation" set. For example if you only set the child pipeline in the "Build Validation", then only the child's status will be displayed in the pr. But because the "build completion triggers" is set, when the status of the child in the pull request is successful, it means that the parent is also successful.

Besides, you can set the Build Validation of the "child" pipeline to **Manual** trigger. Although this will not be able to achieve fully automation, but it can meet the needs of checking the status of the two pipelines in the pr and the order of execution of the two pipelines.

[image]